# How do I change my Minecraft username during the 30-day restriction?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do I change my name in minecraft name earlier than the 30 days please, I need help. My name is really dumb and I would like to change it early.

- I do not hack and I would like to change it early with NO hacks.
- I already looked up this question but I got no help .
  I tried looking up and I am quite impatient.
  https://account.mojang.com/me is the link I used

Comment: Basically, you're asking us to teach you how to bypass the name changing service Mojang offers.  Since that's considered illegal content, I'm voting to close this question as such.

Comment: And again, not illegal, @oamlyya. To be illegal, the action needs to go against the **laws of the country**. This action might be against the terms of service, but breaking terms of service is not considered an illegal action, in itself.

Comment: It is illegal because, by Mojang ToS, name changes are limited to every 30 days. To go against that by some workaround is simply a violation of that TOS.

Comment: Ehh.  That's a stretch of illegality.  There's no reference to piracy or helping cheat.  I can see it maybe being something we can't help with, such as a custom off-topic reason, but illegal?  Nope.  We have a proper answer; you can't.  That doesn't make the question about illegalities.

Comment: @oamlyya Where in the TOS/EULA does it say that?

Comment: The whole point of the 30 day restriction is to restrict you from changing your name for 30 days. Simple as that. Just wait the 30 days as the only way this would be possible is hacks

Comment: @senpai Again, there's a difference between something being illegal and something being against ToS. I suggest you don't use the word "illegal" where it doesn't apply. It's like calling someone who got a speeding ticket a "criminal": sure they did something wrong, but not the kind of thing that lands you in jail.

Answer (score 15):

Simple answer: You can't. Unless you buy another account, your account is stuck with that name until the 30 days are up. You could try contacting Mojang or Microsoft (or whoever owns it now) and get them to change it for you, but I doubt they will.

Anyway, 30 days isn't that long, I'm sure you can live with it until then.

Comment: Contacting Mojang would be a better bet than contacting Microsoft, but just waiting it out is still probably the best choice.

Answer (score 2):

Long answer short: You can't.

For the name change you need to wait 30 days exactly to change  your username.

**BUT WAIT**

Your username is protected for 37 days just in case you made a mistake, aren't connected to the internet, or can't go on Mojang. This was made so people can't steal your username after time is up. 
Hope I helped you!!