# how to change name back within 30 days on minecraft java

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Recently my minecraft account was hacked. I was lucky and got an email from mojang asking to confirm if it was me who logged in and changed my name. I changed that password and kicked out any logged in people. When i logged back on I noticed that my username and skin was changed. I changed my skin back and then tried to change back my username. It said i had to wait 30 days. I was wondering if i am able to email mojang or anyone on their support team about this. anyways im really hoping some people can help. (I WILL NOT HACK OR DO ANYTHING ILLEGAL)

Comment: Name changes are locked for 30 days but your old name cannot be grabbed by anyone else for 37 days, to give time for a revert. Which means your old name is safe! I'm not sure if support can do anything about this, you should probably try contacting them and they might revert it for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change my Minecraft username during the 30-day restriction?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/240916/how-do-i-change-my-minecraft-username-during-the-30-day-restriction)

Answer (score -1):

Don't worry, you can change your name back after 30 days. Names are locked to you for 37 days meaning you have a week to change it back. Just wait and then change it back to your name. You might be able to contact support about it and get changes reverted sooner as well.

Comment: i dont see what is wrong with this